# summation combinatoric again with floor function

Tags: combinatorics, summation

$\sum_{n=1}^{33}\binom{3n}{\left \lfloor 1.5n-0.5 \right \rfloor}= ...$

$\binom{3}{\left \lfloor 1 \right \rfloor}+\binom{6}{\left \lfloor 2.5 \right \rfloor}+\binom{9}{\left \lfloor 4 \right \rfloor}+\binom{12}{\left \lfloor 5.5 \right \rfloor}+...$

it become

$\binom{3}{1}+\binom{6}{2}+\binom{9}{4}+\binom{12}{5}+...$

How i make this summation? I dont know how to evaluate it, I know the floor function but i dont how to do with the combin. Is there any combinatoric identity that i can use to solve it?

Comment: What makes you think it exists?

Comment: It's just asking you to calculate and then add up 33 numbers. What's the difficulty?

Comment: i know to calculate up to 33, but it needs much time. Is there another way to calculate the summation without doing it one by one (combin)?

Comment: I don't know. Why don't you calculate the first few partial sums (1st term; sum of first 2 terms; sum of first 3 terms; and so on) to see whether there's any pattern you can use?

Comment: I've been doing that, but i still cant find the pattern. But i'm still working on it. i havent give up.